# Error uploading to ATtiny

Tags: avr, avrdude

I followed Great Scott's video on YouTube for uploading to an ATtiny85. When I tried I got the following error messages:

> Arduino: 1.6.7 (Windows Vista), Board: "ATtiny85 (internal 8 MHz clock)"
>
> Board attiny-master:attiny:attiny85-20 doesn't define a 'build.board' >preference. Auto-set to: ATTINY_ATTINY85-20
>
> Board attiny-master:attiny:attiny45-8 doesn't define a 'build.board' >preference. Auto-set to: ATTINY_ATTINY45-8
>
> Board attiny-master:attiny:attiny85-8 doesn't define a 'build.board' >preference. Auto-set to: ATTINY_ATTINY85-8
>
> Board attiny-master:attiny:attiny44 doesn't define a 'build.board' >preference. Auto-set to: ATTINY_ATTINY44

etc. etc. ...

> exec: "-w": executable file not found in %PATH%
> Error compiling.`
>
> This report would have more information with
> "Show verbose output during compilation"
> enabled in File > Preferences.

When I unplug  my ATtiny85 and restart Arduino, I have no problems uploading, though I get about 8 error messages saying something like:

> Board attiny-master:attiny:attiny84 doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: ATTINY_ATTINY84

Comment: Please edit question and add a link to whatever video you mean, and a link to the file you downloaded to set up `boards.txt` for those processors.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that a compiler's file name is missing from a command line the IDE is trying to execute.  To find out more about what the command looks like (which will let you figure out what name is missing), turn on verbose output during compilation.  That is, click File, Preferences in the IDE, then click the box in front of “compilation”.  After you find out what's missing, you can then turn off verbose output and fix `platform.txt`, which is the file the IDE looks at to find out what commands to execute when compiling sketches.

To get rid of the warnings about undefined `build.board` values, add lines like the following to the `boards.txt` file in the `tiny/avr/` directory (or whereever you installed it).  (Your 1.6 IDE wants `build.board` definitions, which IIRC weren't needed by 1.5 and earlier IDEs.)

```
attiny85-20.build.board=ATTINY_ATTINY85-20
```

Each of the lines you add will contain the Auto-set value, prefaced by a string made up of a board-type and `.build.board=` concatenated together.  Add each line just before or after other `.build.`-containing lines.